# Pop! OS can an AMD APU and Nvidia 2060 KO work simultaneously

Tags: nvidia, amd-graphics, pop-os

I have had an AMD 3400G for a while and purchased an Nvidia 2060 KO more recently. I'm surprised that when I plug each into their own monitors I only have one working at a time and it's the one that is set up as the initial display per the BIOS. I have a mini-ITX AORUS Pro Wifi I MB if it matters. I'm using Pop! OS but also noticed when I boot into Windows it too does not make use of the display. I also have Manjaro available.

Ultimately I'm trying to see if I can use the Nvidia card as a GPU pass thru for [Macos-Simple-KVM](https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM) while using the APU for the host.